# Add the text of the th to a data attribute in the td in that column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make some contents dynamic so every time a content for the `<th>` is written (like "Name"), that content is stored in a var and attributed to the data-th attribute of the `<td>`, but this must be done in the proper order. So: 
`<th scope="col">Color</th>` has the content "Color" and let's say it's the second child, the second `<td>` child element in each `<tr>` should have:
`<td data-th="Color">Lorem Ipsum</td>`

This is the output I want to create:

```html
<div class="table-color-bg fake-table-bg">
  <table class="fake-table fake-table-simple table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-th="Name">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Company">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Description">Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-th="Name">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Company">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Description">Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-th="Name">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Company">Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td data-th="Description">Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y question. Sure it's possible to do this, but it's a rather odd thing to be doing and whatever your goal is could probably be achieved in a better way (relating elements by index for example)

Comment: Where and how are you triyng that? How are new th's on your table added dynamically?

Comment: I would like to make this with jQuery. The th are being added by a CMS

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need a script similar to this (using `jQuery` library):

```
$('th').on('update-column', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var value = $(this).text();

    $('td').eq(index).data(value);
});
```

Secondly, everytime you will change `<th>`'s content.
You should trigger the `update-column` event like:

```
var th = $(th).eq(1);
th.text('Color');
th.trigger('update-column');
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this